# No sound on Debian 7 stable

Tags: audio, debian, alsa, debian-wheezy, gstreamer

I have Debian 7.1. Today I have lost an ability to listening to music. I can hear sound played by `speaker-test`, `mplayer` and some applications sound (eg. Skype sound notifications). But I have problems with playing music by Rhythmbox or Spotify. When I type: `alsactl init` I receive:

> Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Intel CougarPoint HDMI"
>   "HDA:10ec0889,1458a002,00100004 HDA:80862805,80860101,00100000"
>   "0x1458" "0xa002" Hardware is initialized using a generic method

When I run Rhythmbox from console I get this notification:

> (rhythmbox:7022): Rhythmbox-WARNING **: Unable to grab media player
>   keys: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name
>   org.gnome.SettingsDaemon was not provided by any .service files

I've tried to reinstall gstreamer packages and alsa packages but it didn't help.

I've checked if sound output isn't muted but it isn't.

Comment: Does the problem persist after a reboot?

Comment: Yes, but I have already found the solution. I use MATE which has problem in sound preferences. I log in using Gnome and I found in sound settings that it was set bad output device. I had to press by mistake some keys combination which switched it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found the solution. I use MATE which has problem in sound preferences. I log in using Gnome and I found in sound settings that it was set bad output device. I had to press by mistake some keys combination which switched it.

1. I log in to Gnome Shell session.
2. I go to Sound settings (speaker icon on the top panel)
3. Go to devices tab
4. Switch to right device to which your speakers are plugged.

I have to underline that it was my mistake that it happened. This answer could be useful for everybody who has similar problem.